# LinkedList isPalindrome check always returns True

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

1st if check is to ensure left i.e starting node and right i.e ending node data if they do not match false is returned, but control flow is not returned out of function, instead it keeps matching for other nodes and runs else condition for other cases.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0
        self.tail = None
        self.left = None        

    def palindromeHelper(self,right):
        if(right == None):
            return True

        rres = self.palindromeHelper(right.next)

        print(self.left.data, right.data)
        if self.left.data != right.data:
            return False
        else:
            self.left = self.left.next
            return True

    def isLinkedListPaliendrome(self):
        right = self.left = self.head
        print(self.palindromeHelper(right))

list4 = LinkedList()
list4.addLast('b')
list4.addLast('a')
list4.addLast('c')
list4.addLast('a')
list4.addLast('b')
list4.addLast('a')

list4.isLinkedListPaliendrome()


Output: 
b a
b b
a a
c c
a a
b b
True
```

Comment: Where is `addLast` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overall strategy makes sense:

1. Set a pointer to the front of the list.
2. Recursively get to the end of the list.
3. As the call stack unwinds (essentially moving backward through the list), move the pointer you set at the first step forward, comparing the data.

The trouble is you're ignoring intermediate False results. Consider this input:

`abc`

Note that no letter occurs twice. Let's see what happens:

1. left=a, right=a
2. left=a, right=b
3. left=a, right=c
4. left=a, right=null, return True
5. Now the stack starts to unwind. Left=a, right=c, return False
6. left=a, right=b, return False
7. left=a, right=a, move left to left.next (left=b), return True

Any string with a unique starting letter will return True because of this. In fact, many types of string will will return True, because the algorithm only considers the final comparison, ignoring intermediate failures.

What you need to do is use the intermediate result `rres`. If any step returns False, the whole call stack needs to return False as well.